# UltraGridColumn with button

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

how do I edit the properties of the button created after setting the property:

```
columnUltraGrid.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.EditButton;
```

I would like to add an image and remove the edges of it or just remove the edges and add a word, but then it would have to resize it. If it is not possible to edit, any idea of how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the button will be shown using the OS theme. To be able to set the appearance of the cell button you need first to turn off the OS themes:

```
this.ultraGrid1.UseOsThemes = DefaultableBoolean.False;
```

Then you can set the ButtonStyle and CellButtonAppearance of the Override:

```
e.Layout.Override.CellButtonAppearance.Image = MyImage;
e.Layout.Override.ButtonStyle = UIElementButtonStyle.Borderless;
```